# Rails: Custom attributes for a form created at run time by an Admin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I am new to Rails. Let's say there's an Admin of a web app who can set extra fields required when a user submits a form.

For example, in a bug tracking system, Admin can set a 'checkbox' and labeled "Promised to client?". So whenever anyone enters a bug, they should be submitting this information. This can also later be changed or even removed. All depends on Admin.

So I want Admin to have following options when they create Custom Fields for a Bug entry form...

1. 'Field name' text input
2. 'Field type' dropdown list with values of "checkbox", "text input", "textarea" etc
3. 'Required' a checkbox if this is required for a Bug entry

If anyone has an example on how to do this and especially how to properly validate (server side, without JS) such custom fields, it would be awesome.

If it's important, I am using MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

1. Install nested form gem - https://github.com/ryanb/nested_form
2. Add Bug and CustomField models:

   ```
   model Bug
     has_many :custom_fields
     accepts_nested_attributes_for :custom_fields, allow_destroy: true
   end

   model CustomField
     belongs_to :bug
     validates :name, presence: true
     enum field_type: ["checkbox", "text input", "textarea"]
   end
   ```
3. Read nested_form Usage to add nested fields to bug form.